# amazon ec2-user yum not woring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created one instant on Amazon EC2-user then I installed some application on it after some time 'yum' not working it gives following error for every command

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper


File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/ykenstudio.repo, line: 1
'<html>\r\n'
```

file content

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you copy and paste the content in `/etc/yum.repos.d/ykenstudio.repo`, seems has issue in the first line.

```
file:///etc/yum.repos.d/ykenstudio.repo, line: 1
```

with the comments, seems my guess is correct. The repo file `/etc/yum.repos.d/ykenstudio.repo` are changed to wrong html file, which you need restore it back.

Comment: that's html file, not repo file. You did some changes on it.

Comment: How to restore it back?

Comment: no idea. This file is a customised file, if you don't have snapshot as backup, i can't help. Are there any other similar ec2 instances running in your environment?